# Not able to add rows to dynamically generated table via onclick event handler using Jquery

Tags: jquery, rows

I'm in the process of creating tables dynamically and appending rows to them dynamically as well, all done via Jquery, creating of tables dynamically is fine but not appending rows to the tables, this is how my code looks like, onclick event handler on button is doing nothing, where have I gone wrong? However, if I hardcode the tableID, it seems to work, like so : $("#1 tr:last").after(newRow);

Thanks for your time guys.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {               
            var tableID = 1;
            $('#btnAddSOWG').click(function(){createNewGroup(tableID++);});

            function createNewGroup(RecID) 
            {                   
                var table       = document.createElement('table'); 
                table.id        = RecID;
                var newRow      = table.insertRow();
                var oCell       = newRow.insertCell();
                oCell.innerHTML = "Work Group : <input type='text' name='t1'>";                                 

                var button      = document.createElement('input'); 
                button.type     = "button"; 
                button.id       = 'btn'+ RecID; 
                button.value    = 'Add Work Item';                  
                button.onclick  = function(){createNewItem(RecID);}

                oCell.appendChild(button);

                $('body').append(table);
            } 


            function createNewItem(tableID)
            {                                   
                var selector = "#" +tableID;
                var newRow= "<tr><td><input type='text' name='t1'><td></tr>";   
                $(selector," tr:last").after(newRow);

            } 
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type=button id="btnAddSOWG" value="Add Group">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following one inside createNewItem method:

```
$(selector+" tr:last").after(newRow);
```

I think it should be '+' instead of ','.

Comment: @Karthi, awesome ! Just one more query now, is it possible to create this line dynamically and add onblur event to it ? "<tr><td><input type='text' name='t1'><td></tr>";

Comment: Suppose if you have a table row already, then you can easily add a new row dynamically using clone method. `$(selector+" tr:last").clone(true).insertAfter(selector+" tr:last");`. To add blur, refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/blur#)

Comment: @Karthi, this line $(selector+" tr:last").clone(true).insertAfter(selector+" tr:last"); just builds new tables dynamically when it is supposed to do what function createNewItem(tableID) is doing.

Comment: yes correct santosh, it builds a new row. onblur event can be captured using `$(":input").live('blur', function() {
  //do stuff
});
`